# Titanium Studio crashing the application when I am changing the tabs?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am developing android application, using Titanium studio 3.2.1. In tab group while changing the tabs first time it is working fine second time it shows a black screen, if I tap android:back button it shows the screen, again I came to the same screen, the app getting crash.

```
[WARN][InputMethodManagerService(  475)] Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41e8e568 attribute=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41e8b3a8, token = android.os.BinderProxy@41c1ebb0
```

my code is

```
tabGroup.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
        if (e.index != e.previousInde) {

            switch (e.previousIndex) {
                case 0:
                    winA.fireEvent('blur', e);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    winB.fireEvent('blur', e);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    winC.fireEvent('blur', e);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    winD.fireEvent('blur', e);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    winE.fireEvent('blur', e);
                    break;
            }

            switch (e.index) {
                case 0:
                    winA.fireEvent('focus', e);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    winB.fireEvent('focus', e);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    winC.fireEvent('focus', e);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    winD.fireEvent('focus', e);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    winE.fireEvent('focus', e);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

will any one please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: My Main window I kept like this,                                  var win = Ti.UI.createWindow ({
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    fullScreen: true,
    navBarHidden: true,
    exitOnClose: true 
});

Comment: I gone through this link but I didn't get what I have to do, in my app http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/38-titanium-mobile/140-titanium-mobile-dynamic-tabgroups-on-android